# Downloading A File In IE: Possible?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

So, the idea of downloading a file in an HTML5 compliant version of IE and/or Safari has been long argued over the fact that the download attribute is not support, yet I feel hot on the trail of a solution.

I have file content as a string that I would like to export as an Excel Speadsheet:

```
"data:text/csv;charset=UTF-8,...."
```

Is it possible to load this file content in Javascript as a `document` object? My idea is that, since I can use:

```
document.execCommand("SaveAs", true, "Export.csv");
```

..then I should be able to download my CSV if I can render it as a `document` object! Is this possible? **`DOMParser`?**

Thanks!

Comment: DOMParser is made for XML not CSV

Comment: Yea, I know that @litelite , I was suggesting a back-door operation possibility.

Comment: what do you mean by back-door?